# Multiple Unique Lists from Master List in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of companies with multiple contacts for each company, but I would like to create separate lists with 1 unique contact per company. E.g.

Original list 
Name     Company    Email
John       AAA           john@aaa.com
David       AAA                        david@aaa.com
Jane       BBB                        jane@bbb.com
Julia       CCC                        julia@ccc.com 
Craigh       CCC                        craig@ccc.com
John       CCC                        john@ccc.com

In this case,  to have 1 unique record from each company in a separate list, I want to end up with 3 separate lists:

List 1
Name         Company                        Email
John                            AAA                         john@aaa.com
Jane                            BBB                         jane@bbb.com
Julia                           CCC                         julia@ccc.com

List 2
Name                          Company                   Email
David                          AAA                     david@aaa.com
Craigh                         CCC                      craig@ccc.com

List 3
Name                          Company                    Email
John                            CCC                      john@ccc.com

As you can see in each list there is only 1 record for each company.

Any help on how to do this would be most appreciated.

I have tried advance filter to list unique records only by selecting the entire original list as the range and setting the company column as the criteria see the unique records which I could then select visible cells and cut to a different list, and then re-run the filter again to create the next set of unique records etc...but the advance filter doesn't give the results as expected.

-

-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a silly idea but still worth trying... Add a helper column with Count formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:B2,B2)
```

[image]

Apply Filter and Sort your data set by the fourth column (Sort Smallest to Largest):

[image]

This seems to match your Table 1, 2 & 3 output.

Alternatively, if you still want to create separate tables, you can use the helper column and array formulas (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) as per example below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$7,SMALL(IF($D$1:$D$7=1,ROW($D$1:$D$7)),ROW()-1),COLUMN()-5),"")
```

Change `$D$1:$D$7=1` to `=2` and `=3` to replicate the 2nd and the 3rd table.

[image]

**Edit:** with additional "Location" column

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:B2,B2,$D$1:D2,D2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JvdV ! I guess sometimes the most silly / simple solutions are the best :)

Comment: Hi

Thanks for this suggestions. It will work for small lists. When you have 1000s of rows to work with, going through each row and putting in a serial number is not possible.

I see that the remove duplicates feature takes away all rows of a duplicate value in a specific column except the first one in the duplicate list. 

If I can run a "remove duplicates to another sheet" somehow, then it would be a way around solution. So I remove duplicates to another sheet, and re-run the "remove duplicates to another sheet" again and again.

Comment: @Vocabridge All you need to do is enter the formula in the first cell of the helper column, and fill down to the bottom of the table. It shouldn't take more than a few seconds.

Comment: Agreed with @RonRosenfeld , I just expanded the data set up to the 10,000th row and copied down the helper column's formula - it took just a few seconds to calculate. Please give it a try and let us know the results.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld woohoo it actually does work...thanks a million.

The other little challenge I would like to throw in there is:

If you added a another column called Location and so now the numbering should be done in sequence only for the SAME company AND same Location. But if the company is same, but location is different, then the count should start again...if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Vocabridge I think adding additional condition to `COUNTIFS` formula should help. I just edited my answer, give it a try.

Comment: @JustynaMK you're amazing. Thank you a million. This has saved me 10s of hours of work! I've even tried buying Kutools addon and contacted their support team only to find that they cannot do it and your contribution here has made a huge difference. Thanks

Comment: No problem at all @Vocabridge, glad it all worked for you! It's very nice to see how the magic of Excel is benefiting others :) feel free to upvote / mark my answer as correct - see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more details. Take care.